# SharePoint 2016 NLB Issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, nlb

I have a three tier architecture where I have 5 front end servers, 2 app servers and 2 DB servers.

Now there is a load balancer which is configured for the SharePoint application, now when i try to access the application outside the server I face an issue sometimes and sometimes it works fine. I tried running the url by specifying the IP of servers individually in lm host file, which worked accurately.

Now is there a way through which I can point the application to only one web front end server and skip the rest three.

Note: I have no idea on network load balancer implemented in the system. I'm looking for a way out by just pointing to one front end server.

Comment: You're going to want to work with your network folks to see how it is implemented. The VIP should only point to SharePoint FEs (make sure IIS Bindings are properly configured on each one) and should be using sticky (persistent) sessions.

Answer (score 1):

It will all depend on how the LB is implemented. Best to discuss it with Network team (if they manage the LB)

Simple way of pointing LB to one server is just stopping the web app in other servers. If the LB monitor is set up correctly it will find out the other servers are down and point traffic to server that has the app enabled.

I wouldn't recommend that option for PROD servers. I use it all the time in QA as opening ticket for our Network team and resolving it can take up to 2 days. This is much faster method for testing (as in our set up we use SSL offloading, pointing host file to servers is not always an option).